# Should we create tags for popular animal models used for study? e.g fruit-flies

Tags: discussion, tags

## Q1: Should we create tags for popular animal models used for study?

I think the use of some animal specific tags could attract answers from that animal expert. This would allow an expert of the `Göttingen-minipig` or `Naked-mole-rat` which are widely used in laboratory study to subscribe to these tags.

## Q2: If we do create tags for certain animals, how would we determine which ones qualify as a tag?

I would see both the benefit of creating tags for very specific animals like `pangolins` or `Aedes aegypti` but also I can see the benefit of creating tags for very popular animals that are encountered in biology, like `pandas` or `chimpanzees`

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't think there are enough questions in this area of research to warrant specific tags for them. More importantly, the question would have to be specifically about that species and very likely a question on a species A could also be answered by considering a related species A'. If it's true for a brown rat, it probably applies to a black one as well. In fact, translational research is often at play. We are making educated guesses in species B, because they are expected to relate to a distant species Z.