# tag proposal: "c.elegans" or "caenorhabditis elegans"

Tags: feature-request

Do you think interesting a tag "Caenorhabditis elegans" ( "c.elegans" for friends :-) ? It seems not available and my reputation is far from the necessary to create it.

Comment: To back up your request: I a quick search I've found 50 questions that contained "elegans".

Comment: [This recent Meta-post](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/should-we-create-tags-for-popular-animal-models-used-for-study-e-g-fruit-flies) is related.

Answer (score 5):

I am in general not a fan of tags for particular model organisms.

From my perspective, the point of model organisms is that they are *models* - the relevant tags are to the biology being studied. Except for some very narrow cases relevant to the model organism itself (in which case the [model-organism](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-organism) tag is appropriate), few people 'care' about *C. elegans* specifically, they are just using that organism as a tool to infer something about biology more broadly. Development, molecular biology, neural circuits are all possible tags that are more useful.